# Ubuntu 22 home screen doesn't work correctly

Tags: 22.04, screen, workspaces

My home screen doesn't work correctly, at different times right click shows a different context menu, if I add a home folder the folder icon starts flickering. Also, I noticed in the system monitor that the `apport` process is constantly running every ~15 seconds.

In `/var/crash`:
_usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.crash   _usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.uploaded
_usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.upload

It looks like the process responsible for the home screen is constantly rebooting, the background does not change in any way.

```
:/$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
    DeviceName: Second VGA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 131d
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
0000:01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] (rev a1)
    DeviceName: VGA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

[Home screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpM3Z.jpg)

[Home screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIIDl.jpg)

[Home screen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8lyT.jpg)

[About my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7EA9.png)

[image: Drivers]

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: @Pilot6 I add screenshot of drivers

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 output added

Comment: Drivers look good. Try to boot from LiveUSB and check how it works there. If it is OK, then it is some setting you did.